# Linux Server Performance Monitoring

Tags: linux, centos, performance, performance-monitoring

I'm looking to monitor performance on my Linux servers (which happen to be Centos).  What are the best tools for monitoring things in realtime such as:

- Disk Performance I/O, swapping etc..
- CPU Performance

Looking for low level tools, rather than web based tools such as Nagios, Ganglia etc...

**n.b.** I'd like to know exactly what each tool does rather than just having a list of random toolnames if possible please.  Why the tool is a better option than others would be good also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[collectl](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a great performance monitor with some unique and advanced [features](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/Features.html) like InfiniBand and Lustre support or environmental and NFS monitoring. Of course it does basic stuff like disk and cpu monitoring, too. Highly recommended!

Comment: This is pretty cool, used it tonight on some disk I/O monitoring... working well... thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 12):

iostat, sar, top, munin

Comment: Simple and to the point, I like it!

Comment: +1 for munin, very easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently release collectl-utils which provided graphing capabilities for collectl data with a web-based tool called colplot.  The one key thing with this accuracy.  Using gnuplot for the the graphics it's very fast and shows every data point, unlike RRD which 'normalizes' your data.
-mark

Answer (score 0):

Doing a Google search for "linux monitoring tools", you find some stuff.

One of the good links found: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html  This article tells you what each tool does, and will give you an idea why one tool is better than another for a particular purpose.

The tools mezgani recommended are listed in that article, except [Munin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munin_(network_monitoring_application)).  Munin doesn't seem to be what you are looking for anyway (it is web-based and you specifically said you didn't want web-based).

Answer (score 0):

u can check same of very useful tool of open source.

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/10/linux-system-monitoring-tools-every.html

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/10/linux-limit-cpu-usage-per-process.html

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want decent historical data graphing, especially for multiple systems, check out Cacti.  It requires configuring SNMP on each system (easy).

Answer (score 0):

If you want graph easy your Linux performance, try Bijk.com:

Open source tool with web access and live graphs! http://www.bijk.com

Comment: original question "Looking for low level tools, rather than web based tools"

Answer (score 0):

Use atop, that will give you percentage of how much each resource is busy. Also it color codes data and if something is botteling out system resources it will color code those entries.

In CentOS you can install it from EPEL/RPMForge repos.

//Christian

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are looking for low level tools. But you might want to rethink as I believe performance monitoring is a regular exercise. From my experience I can tell how difficult it can become if you don't use dedicated tools. These are the tools I came across.

1. [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)
2. [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/)
3. [SeaLion](https://sealion.com)