# Recommendations for monitoring and logging system resources?

Tags: performance-monitoring

I'd like to have the ability to log and record various resources: CPU, memory, disk IOPS, etc of a machine so I can test its capabilities.

The purpose of this software is to test my own applications and memory usage of them.

I mainly use Ubuntu, but I also admin servers with Centos4/5 as well.

I am also interested to know what large providers use for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to monitor machines that area attached to a network, take a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers). It's very, very good.

But, if you intend to monitor a standalone machine (as you said), you could use [SAR](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar). It's a tool to collect and report system activity. [This post](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/52570) and [this post](http://www.ozzu.com/unix-linux-forum/howto-system-monitoring-with-the-sysstat-package-t67717.html) can help you to understand the big picture. [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/74863/linux-server-performance-monitoring) is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

Most monitoring systems are designed for exactly that - measuring the behaviour of a live system over a long period of time. There are lots of tools available for doing this - Bob's answer here gives links to some of the stuff available.

However there are a couple of problems with this.

First these are not really setup for testing purposes - you're going to have to think about how you reconcile these metrics with your testing.

Secondly, while the standard system metrics can give a good pointer to how performance is constrained - they don't actually measure transactional performance. The important thing is to deliver the data the user requests promptly - not to keep the CPU usage below some arbitrary value - so you need to think about how you measure actual end-to-end performance.

The other thing to bear in mind, is that application tuning is a very empirical art - you're going to have to colelct and **visualize** a lot of data - most of the monitoring tools aren't really very good for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cacti](http://www.cacti.net) to log CPU usage, Memory usages, and disk read/write cycles and test your app for example with ab(or in other way)  ..then analize cacti graphs

Answer (score 0):

[Nimsoft](http://www.nimsoft.com/news/press-releases/2010-04-07-rackspace.php), amongst other things.